# Installing Google Sitemap Generator on Linux

Tags: google, google-search-console, apache, sitemap, linux

I have a website with httpd (front end) and Apache tomcat (back end).

I'm trying to install Google Sitemap Generator and create sitemap for the website.

I followed the following link for installation:

http://googlesitemapgenerator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/gsg-installation.html

But I'm not able to load `http://server:8181`, it is showing a blank page.

My system details are:
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
httpd-2.2.3-65.el5.centos
apache-tomcat-6.0.37

I'm using mod_jk connectors for connecting Apache and Tomcat. 
Here is my mod_jk configurations:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkMount /* worker1
JkShmFile  /etc/httpd/logs/jk-runtime-status
```

This is my *worker.properties* file:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
workers.tomcat_home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/
workers.java_home=/usr/java/default
ps=/
worker.list=worker1
worker.default.port=8009
worker.default.host=localhost
worker.default.type=ajp13
```

I have installed Google Sitemap Generator and gave me final result. 
Google Sitemap Generator daemon successfully started.
To start the Google Sitemap Generator module in Apache, you must restart Apache.
After you restart Apache, you can go to `http://<this-server-address>:8181/` to
configure the application.
Google Sitemap Generator (Beta) was successfully installed.

But the problem is I can not access `mydomain:8181`.

Is it necessary to configure ssl?
if I give `mydomain.com:8181` it is redirecting to `mydomain.com`.
I have no idea why.

If I use Lynx from command line. 
`lynx http://domain.com:8181` gives a blank page.

Comment: Are there any messages in the the apache log files that would shed some additional light on the situation?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller: Unfortunately there is no error logs. The thing is if I give domain.com:8181 apache is forwarding it to tomcat. is there anyway to prevent this? is there anyway to prevent the forwarding of http on port 8181 only? in mod_jk.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able unmount mod_jk in your virtual host settings for port 8181.

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ....
    JkUnMount  / NameOfJkMountGoesHere
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

I would also suggest looking into using mod_proxy to forward your requests to Tomcat.  I run Tomcat as http on port 8080 and my front end Apache connects to it over HTTP using mod_proxy.  This is a much simpler setup (and protocol) than mod_jk.  I put the mod_proxy settings directly in each virtual host so that they only apply to the specific site that I want to forward to tomcat.

Comment: `JkUnMount  / NameOfJkMountGoesHere`

worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a firewall setting.   I recently had problems accessing a port where I was trying to run a service because my firewall was disallowing it.

Comment: its not firewall settings problem. I can telnet to port 8181 from other servers using public ips.